# What is this werid grey box after I click a button element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xeEK.png)

This is a html, css and JS tic tac toe game I am trying to code. When I click on the start button and even after it a gray box appears around the element. I’ve tried to inspect it but I have never seen this before and I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Impossible to say for sure without looking at the code, but you should be sure to specify in the CSS that there's no border on click or hover............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem, it is the normally expected behaviour. The box provides visual feedback for links that have "focus" when navigating a web document. This style is provided by your browser, if you do not override it.

Try overriding it like this:

```
yourElement:focus {
outline: 0;
}
```

You don't want to do this for regular content (http://www.outlinenone.com/) though.